# Move to next stage even current stage failed in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have one Jenkins pipeline where I'm running five tests in parallel, and then I'm archiving artifacts of all the tests in one folder. The issue I'm facing is that if one of the tests fails, the rest of the tests still build, but the pipeline ends with failure, and it doesn't archive the artifacts.

This is how my pipeline looks like.

```
`stage("Test") {
    steps {
        parallel (
            test1: {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'SUCCESS') {
                    script {
                        def sql_run_tag = "${params.sql_run_tag}"
                            if (params.sql_run_tag == 'skip') {
                                sql_run_tag = "Sanity-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                            }
                            else {
                                sql_run_tag = "${params.sql_run_tag}"
                            }
                        def build_test1 = build (
                            job: 'test1',
                            wait: true,
                            parameters: [
                                string(name: 'xx', value: params.xx),
                                string(name: 'yy', value: params.yy),
                                string(name: 'zz', value: params.zz),
                                string(name: 'aa', value: params.aa),
                                string(name: 'sql_run_tag', value: "${sql_run_tag}"),
                                string(name: 'test_template', value: params.test_template),
                                string(name: 'run_category', value: params.run_category),
                                string(name: 'upstream_build_number', value: get_build_number)
                            ]
                        )
                        get_build_test1 = build_test1.getNumber().toString()
                        copyArtifacts(
                            projectName: 'test1',
                            selector: specific("${build_test1.getNumber().toString()}"),
                            filter: 'output_files/**/*',
                            target: 'results/test1'
                        )
                        post {
                            always {
                                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/Runs/xx/results/**/*' , fingerprint: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )    
    }
}`
```

I tried catch error and put it as a success so everytime it passes the test and in archiving artifacts i used the post always step but still it's not archiving the artifacts.

This is my console output.

```
 [Pipeline] // script
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // catchError
 [Pipeline] }
 Build test1 #1118 completed: SUCCESS
 [Pipeline] copyArtifacts
 Copied 18 artifacts from "test1" build number 1118
 [Pipeline] archiveArtifacts
 Archiving artifacts
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // script
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // catchError
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // parallel
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // stage
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // withEnv
 [Pipeline] }
 [Pipeline] // node
 [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `catchError` and `post` statments outside the `parallel` block. With your current configuration, you can also use `try.. catch` within the `script` block so that the post stage is eventually reached even if the previous steps fail. The way your code is set up right now, since the `post` script is inside the `script` section, when something else inside the same section fails, the `post` section will be overlooked and the step will finish.